# How to color the area between two geom_smooth lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have 3 columns in a data frame from which I want to create a visualisation with geom_smooth() :

```
ggplot(my_data_frame) +
  aes(x = fin_enquete,
      y = intentions,
      colour = candidat) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1/6,
             shape = "circle", 
             size = .5L) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(y = erreur_inf),
              size = .5L,
              span = .42,
              se = F) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(y = erreur_sup),
              size = .5L,
              span = .42,
              se = F) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess",
              size = 1.5L,
              span = .42,
              se = F) +
  labs(x = "Date de fin d'enquête", 
       y = "Pourcentage d'intentions de vote") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "DIN Pro")) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = F) +
  easy_remove_legend()
```

[3 lines with geom_smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpQpy.png)

I would like to color the area between the upper and the lower line. I know the geom_ribbon() function but I am not sure I can use it in this situation.

Does anybody have a solution?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `geom_ribbon` and calculate the `loess` model yourself within the `geom_ribbon` call?

Toy random data

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100), y2=runif(100)+1, y3=runif(100)+2)
```

Now suppose we want a smoothed ribbon between `y` and `y3`, with `y2` drawn as a line between them:

```
ggplot( dat , aes(x, y2)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=predict(loess(y~x)), 
                   ymax=predict(loess(y3~x))), alpha=0.3) + 
    geom_smooth(se=F)
```

[image: ggplot]

Comment: I did as you suggested with my data but it gives me this error :

`Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)`

I'm not sure what it means, any clue?

Comment: what happens if you try to run the `loess` model on its own?

Comment: Do you have any `Inf` or `NaN` values in your data?

Comment: The same error with the loess function on its own, I don't have any missing/infinite value in my dataset.

Comment: The x I use is a date, maybe that's it?

Comment: Yes that's it.  If i use a date I get the same error.  I can fix it by using `loess(y~as.numeric(x))` in the `aes` call.

Comment: It won't change the `x` axis in the `geom_ribbon` call so it should be safe

Comment: No problem, glad it worked.  You could accept my answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lapply(`) smooth to calculate the range of df values such as (5,11,13) to calculate the smooths and plot only the two edges of the `se.`

Sample code:

```
      library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       mapping = aes(x = wt,
                     y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  lapply(c(5,11, 13), function (i) {
  geom_smooth(
               data = ~ cbind(., facet_plots = i),
               method = lm,
               se=F,
               formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, i)
              ) 
  })+
    #facet_wrap(vars(facet_plots))
  geom_ribbon( 
              stat = "smooth",
              method = "loess",
              se = TRUE,
              alpha = 0, # or, use fill = NA
              colour = "black",
              linetype = "dotted")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]